# Is it any app which can identify plants from photos?

Tags: identification

Do you know any good app, which can identify flowers, trees, bushes from images like this?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

**[iNaturalist](https://www.inaturalist.org/)** is a free site and application that can help identify plants from pictures. It also uses those images for research and will provide suggestions based on what it finds in the image, providing comparisons for you to see to positively identify the plant.

Making an account is free, and it is relatively easy to use even in a mobile web browser.

A feature of the app/site is that other users will help identify the plant for you.

Answer (score 1):

PlantNet on Android identified a picture of your picture as Euonymus alatus or staghorn sumac. I tend to think the plant is Staghorn sumac but the location and a few other clues would confirm it.

Comment: I thought it was sumac as well; if not in North America, perhaps a different genus of sumac.